# Cassandra: “cqlsh” line 213 Using `%s` instead.\n' ^ % (CONFIG_FILE, HISTORY_DIR) SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: cassandra, cqlsh

Installed Cassandra 2.2. version in CentOS 6 and python 3.4.2 All paths available in environment variables.

File /usr/local/Python-3.4.2/setuptools-12.0.4/pip-6.0.6/p34env/bin/cqlsh

```
 File "/usr/local/Python-3.4.2/setuptools-12.0.4/pip-6.0.6/p34env/bin/cqlsh", line 213
    print '\nWarning: Specified cqlshrc location `%s` does not exist.Using `%s` instead.\n' % (CONFIG_FILE, HISTORY_DIR)
                                                                                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 3):

`cqlsh` supports only Python 2.x, so you need to use correct version of Python to run it.